# How && if loop Expression evaluation?

Tags: java, if-statement

In evaluating the expression `(x==y && a<b)` the Boolean expression `x==y` is evaluated first and then `a<b` is evaluated. True or False????

Please explain the working for the same. I quite confused for this if expression.

Comment: Yes, although `a < b` is only evaluated if `x == y` is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

&& operator evaluates from left to right

If first evaluates x==y first and then a<b, however there is a catch here.
If x==y evaluates to false, anyway the whole expression tends to go false, hence a<b wont be evaluated.  This is the basic optimization we get when we use &&.

If you want the other expression to be evaluated even though the first expression tends to false, we could use & like

```
  (x==y & a<b)
```

Check the following examples:

```
 int x=10,y=9,count=0;
    if(x==y && ++count == 0){
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Output would be 0 in this case

```
 int x=10,y=9,count=0;
    if(x==y & ++count == 0){
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Output would be 1 in this case. Check the operator carefully, we used &

Answer (score 2):

For `&&` (Conditional-And) :-

`x==y` will evaluates first and if that comes true then it will evaluates `a<b`. as Conditional-And evaluate from left to right.

And if you use only `&` operatore :- (And Operator)

In this case both the condition will be evaluated. irrespective of first condition (Left Condition) fail or pass.

Answer (score 0):

`x==y`is evaluated and only if it was true, will `a<b` be evaluated

Answer (score 0):

&& (as AND) and || (as OR) evaluate left expression first and only if it is needed, continue evaluating the second expression.

For example:

- **False && Anything** will always return **False** without evaluating the secong expression.
- **True || Anything** will always return **True**

You can also use & and |, which evaluates both expressions. (If the second expression throws exception, the evaluation will fail.) If you need faster and more secure evaluation, use && and ||.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` will evaluate from left to right. The left expression to the operator `&&` is evalutaed first, if it execute to false then the right expression is never evaluated and if the left expression is true than the right expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is processed left-to-right. If first argument is false then other arguments are ignored. It will process arguments on right **if and only if** all the arguments on the left are true. It is known as [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

In your case, if `x==y` is false then `a<b` will not be evaluated.